# Is there a function to change my months column from int to text without it showing NA

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

I have a df month column like this:

```
"09" "09" "04" "01" "04" "10"
```

And I am trying to convert them to "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"

I have tried this

```
df$months <- month.abb[df$month]
```

and
mymonths <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
df$months <- mymonths[ df$month ]

but my output from the both is:

```
NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Think about what you're trying to use as an index: "09", "01", etc are strings just the same as if you were trying to index by "x", "y", and "z". They might have some meaning _to you_, but they don't represent numbers to your code

Answer (score 2):

We need to convert to `integer` so that it can be used as position index to return the corresponding values of month.abb in that position

```
month.abb[as.integer(df$month)]
```